# iOS video app approach to swipe or pinch to play a different video file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm making an iOS app that has several video files in fullscreen mode between which you should be able to swipe or pinch to play a different video file.

I know MPMoviePlayerController doesn't allow gestures on it and that I'll need to capture the gestures in an overlapped view. But I would love you to share what would your approach be for this task.

Comment: Hi! This question as it is isn't a great fit for the site.. can you perhaps add some code to it?  Much better if you can show something that you've tried! :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm just starting so there is not really much code to show. Next time I'll try not to be so lazy and ask something more specific. Now I just needed a starting point so I don't end up with tons of useless code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site!  As one comment mentioned, StackOverflow is generally more useful for specific questions like "what's wrong with this code" or "how do I get a `UIWebView` to do this" rather than general suggestions about conceptual design.  That being said, I'm a big fan of "point me in the right direction" sort of advice myself, so here's how I'd go about it making an app like you described:

I'm picturing something like the Photos app, swiping back and forth between full-screen content, except that this time it's videos instead of photos, yes?  If so, I'd probably look into `UIScrollView` with paging enabled, or `UICollectionView`.  Either of those will allow you to make a series of full-screen "pages" that you can swipe back and forth between, and you can just add a video to each cell/page.  You could even have the CollectionView programmatically play/pause each video as you switch between them.

The specifics of your app will determine exactly what configuration works best for you, but that's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That "point me in the right direction" advice was what I needed. I'll dig into UIScrollView and UICollectionView and start building the app from there. I'm sure I will find more specific questions for the next time. Thanks!